# How to save generic object to an array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have on class

```
class SomeClass<T>: AsyncOperation, NetworkOperationProtocol {

    /// The resource model object that conforms to Parsable Response
    public typealias Resource = T
}
```

I want to save instance of this class to an array, and want retrieve it later.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want an array of generic types? Something like `[SomeClass<A>(), SomeClass<B>()]`? If so, then it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If your class implements protocol with associatedtype, it's impossible to put it into array because such protocols have Self-requirement - they need to know concrete type for associatedtype.

However, you can use technique called type-erasure to store type without associated type information. So, for example, you can create a protocol without associatedtype, like so

```
protocol Operation {
   func perform()
}

class SomeClass<T> : AsyncOperation, NetworkOperationProtocol, Operation
```

And then define an array of such operations:

```
let operations : [Operation] = []
operations.append(SomeClass.init())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your generic type would be:

```
struct GenericType {}
```

You would specify the generic class using:

```
let array = [SomeClass<GenericType>]()
```

Or you can let it infer the type on its own with something like:

```
class SomeClass<T>: AsyncOperation, NetworkOperationProtocol {

    /// The resource model object that conforms to Parsable Response
    public typealias Resource = T
    let resource: Resource

    init(with resource: Resource) {
        self.resource = resource
    }
}

let item = SomeClass(with: GenericType())
let array = [item]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple 
You can declare an array like this

```
var anArray = [SomeClass<Parsable>]()
```

Please note that while declaring the array I have defined the `Parsable` instead of T.

If you don't know the type of T while creating array. You can go following way

```
var anArray = [AnyObject]()

let anObject = SomeClass<Parsable>()
anArray.append(anObject)

if anArray[0] is SomeClass<Parsable> {
    print(true)
}
```

Comment: What is Parsable here? I don't know type of T while retrieving.

Comment: In your question I saw in comment Parsable. Its just an example. You need to know the type of T while retrieving.use  if..is  for that.